# How to right use free for data

Tags: c

```
struct str {
uint8_t *data;
};

int main() {
    struct str *buffer;
    free(buffer->data);
}
```

How to right check data before use free ? This example call Segmentation failed ...

Comment: You aren't initialising buffer to anything, so it's pointing to a random address. This is practically guaranteed to fail. I'm not sure what advice you want, beyond, "Don't do that!"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your data has not been allocated. You only create a pointer on a struct str. The correct use is the following:

```
int main() {
  struct str *buffer = (struct str*)malloc(sizeof(struct str));
  if (buffer == NULL) { fprintf(stderr, "Error with malloc\n"); exit (EXIT_FAILURE); }
  buffer->data = (uint8_t*)malloc(sizeof uint8_t);
  if (buffer->data == NULL) { fprintf(stderr, "Error with malloc\n"); exit (EXIT_FAILURE); }
  // Process data here
  free(buffer->data);
  free(buffer);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your example you're freeing an unitialized pointer, which most often will cause a seg fault. There's no way of testing a pointer before you free it so you will have to make sure that you only free valid pointers (i.e. one returned from malloc etc).

**EDIT:** As several has pointed out, since `buffer` isn't initialized the mere act of accessing `buffer->data` will also cause a segfault.

Comment: The program is not actually trying to free anything; the `buffer->data` dereference is going to trigger a segfault before `free()` is even entered.

Answer (score 1):

You can free() only pointers returned from malloc() or realloc(). Given an arbitrary pointer, it is not possible to check whether it can be freed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to allocate memory for this, before calling `free`. If it's uninitialized, `buffer->data` can point anywhere and using `free` on uninitialized pointer is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what's already been said, if you know that a pointer should be used for dynamic memory allocation, always initialize it to NULL.

Both free() and C++ delete are guaranteed to don't do a thing if a NULL pointer is passed to them.

This is the reason why you shall always set the pointer to NULL after freeing it as well.

```
#include <stddef.h>    

int* ptr = NULL;
...
// malloc ptr or don't do a thing

free(ptr);  // won't crash no matter if ptr is allocated or not
ptr = NULL; // ptr is free to be used again
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't allocate any memory, nor initialized the pointer in your code.

An appropriate usage will be something like that:

```
struct str {
uint8_t *data;
};

int main() {
    struct str *buffer;
    buffer = malloca(sizeof(struct str));
    if (buffer == NULL) {
        return 1; // failed to allocate buffer
    }
    buffer->data = malloc(sizeof(uin8_t));
    if (buffer->data == NULL) {
        free(buffer); // failed to allocate data
        return 1;
    }
    free(buffer->data);
    free(buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`free()` is not your (only) problem here.  `buffer` is an uninitialized pointer, so the very act of dereferencing it (`buffer->data`) will almost certainly cause a segfault.  You would also get a segfault if this code were:

```
struct str {
uint8_t *data;
};

int main() {
    struct str *buffer;
    printf("%p\n", buffer->data);
}
```